# C# Getting ClassName: Exception TargetSite.DeclaringType.Name Vs MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaryingType

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling

I am creating a simple logging method (nothing fancy) for the try/catch statements. I want to include the class name and the method where the exception was thrown.

There are two different means by which to get the information. One using the `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()` and the exception `TargetSite`.

I know the MethodBase could possibly add a performance issue, but would be quite insignificant on regular try/catch statements.

I also understand that both could have null values. My question is **which process is preferred, is there any downside or does it even matter**?

Here is my code getting both

```
public static void LogError(Exception exp, MethodBase method) 
{
    var methodName = method.Name;
    var className = (method.ReflectedType != null) ? method.ReflectedType.Name : "";

    var methodName2 = exp.TargetSite!= null ? exp.TargetSite.Name : "";
    var className2 = (exp.TargetSite != null && exp.TargetSite.DeclaringType != null) ? exp.TargetSite.DeclaringType.Name : "";

    // do more stuff
}
```

Here is the call to the method

```
AuditDbContext.LogError(ex, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());
```

If i use the TargetSite, I wouldn't pass in the MethodBase (of course).

**UPDATE:**

Include Caller Information as an additional possible choice. Thanks lliar for the comment.

Comment: Do you want to log the method in which the exception was *thrown* (which is not necessarily where your try/catch is) or where the exception is *caught*? That's what should determine which you use.

Comment: I would like to catch it where the exception is caught.

Comment: Do you consider using [Caller information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information)? See example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dRc0eY.

Comment: @ZombieCode What approach did you finally use to get `ClassName`?

Comment: @IliarTurdushev I ended up using the exception data using TargetSite.It was easier and more logical since I didn't have to pass an additional parameter nor include `System.Reflection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to log class name and method name ***where exception was thrown*** than you should use `Exception.TargetSite`.

`MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()` returns current method. This method can return a method that is different from the method where exception was thrown.

Here is a sample that shows the difference:

```
public static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        Demo();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Output: Program Demo
        Log1(e);

        // Output: Program Main
        Log2(e, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());
    }
}

public static void Demo()
{
    // Exception is thrown in Program.Demo
    throw new Exception();
}

public static void Log1(Exception exp) 
{
    var methodName = exp.TargetSite != null ? exp.TargetSite.Name : "";
    var className = (exp.TargetSite != null && exp.TargetSite.DeclaringType != null) ? exp.TargetSite.DeclaringType.Name : "";
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", className, methodName);
}

public static void Log2(Exception exp, MethodBase method) 
{
    var methodName = method.Name;
    var className = (method.ReflectedType != null) ? method.ReflectedType.Name : "";
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", className, methodName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way for me is to create an Stacktrace and get the Method-name from there. This is the method I use for it:
**Just let me know if you would like to see the whole class I use for the Logging**

---

```
private static void MessageInfoForLog(out string methodName, out string className, int frameDepth)
    {
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
        var frame = stackTrace.GetFrame(frameDepth + 2); //+2 only if you go from your method to Log and log access this method here --> Exception --> Log (1) --> MessageInfoForLog(2)
        var method = frame.GetMethod();

        className = method.ReflectedType.Name;
        methodName = method.Name;
    }
```

---